# Plotly in flask app to measure realtime data

Tags: python, flask, plotly, real-time

I am measuring data from a raspberry pi and want to utilize plotly offline (or any doable graphing package to be honest) to chart the measured data in real time to a flask app with plotly charts embedded.

Honestly I don't even need to use plotly. I have found that the support and documentation is quite unclear for my intents and purposes. I just want my flask app to take the measured data and plot it real time in a web browser. What are the best tools for this? I have never done any front end web programming before so I am quite lost.

Comment: is this https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates of help?

Comment: This requires me to rewrite my app in dash correct?

Comment: not sure about re-write, but yes you would need to use dash which integrates with plotly, they are part of the same stack

Comment: this would require me to setup a license with plotly and dash correct? I am trying to do it so that I do not have to setup a lisence or have any API authentication setup

Comment: no, most part of dash is MIT licensed

Comment: @hgrey Took my a while but worked backwards from the first tutorial and now I have a working Dash webserver! I love it ! The Plotly website does a bad job explaining the open source portion I feel. So thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dash to update plotly charts: [dash live updates](https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates).
Dash open source is MIT licensed and can be embedded into existing or new webapp.